# fetching a specific row when updating a data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a simple CRUD (UPDATE) system.

I already declared the `fetch` variable but it says that it is undefined.

When I'm modifying a data on a specific row I want to see the old data in the textbox before I modify it, but it only shows:

> **Notice:**  Undefined variable: fetch in **D:\IDEs\xampp\htdocs\eam\edit_data.php** on line **85**
>   **Notice:**  Undefined variable: fetch in **D:\IDEs\xampp\htdocs\eam\edit_data.php** on line **89**
>   **Notice**:  Undefined variable: fetch in **D:\IDEs\xampp\htdocs\eam\edit_data.php** on line **93**

Here's my code:

```
        if ($first != '' && $first != ' ' && $last != '' && $last != ' '&& $email != "" && $email != " " && ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ',"", $first)) && ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ',"", $last)) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $mysql_query = "UPDATE register SET fname='$first', lname='$last', email='$email' WHERE id=".$_GET['id'];

            $query3 = mysql_query($mysql_query);
            if($query3)
            {
                header('location: view.php');
            }
            $id=$_GET['id'];
            $query_results = mysql_query("SELECT id, fname, lname, email FROM register WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

            while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query_results))
            {

            }
        }
    }

    ?>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $fetch['id'];?>"/>
            First name:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="fname" style="width: 800px; height: 50px" value="<?php echo $fetch['first'];?>"/>&nbsp;<?php echo $fnameErr; ?>
            <br>
            Last name:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="lname" style="width: 800px; height: 50px" value="<?php echo $fetch['last'];?>"/>&nbsp;<?php echo $lnameErr; ?>
            <br>
            Email:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="email" style="width: 800px; height: 50px" value="<?php echo $fetch['email'];?>"/>&nbsp;<?php echo $emailErr; ?>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Modify"/> 
        </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Im already studying about mysqli...but for now......since mysql_* is the first one that i learned....im gonna use mysql..

Comment: The whole structure of your code is off. You're only query the database if your if statement validates, but you're still trying to use the database result in the form, regardless.

Comment: That is a bad idea. Mysql is insecure, old and deprecated and your code is _very_ insecure. It shouldn't be used _at all_  any more. If this is code that will live out in the public and you will let other people use your app, please respect their private information (which you aren't by knowingly using insecure libraries). Btw, if you rewrite your code using Mysqli or PDO with prepared statements, you might actually restructure your code in such an extent that you will fix your own bugs.

Comment: you declare `$fetch`, sure, but its scope is only within the `while` loop. You can't use it outside that context, as you are currently attempting to do. I suggest you read some tutorials on how to fetch and display data using PHP, because it seems like you haven't got all the key concepts yet. Also, Magnus' comments about the mysql_ libraries are very valid and important. I certainly would not want to be your user/customer if you persist using these functions. And, when the time comes to upgrade to PHP7, your app simply won't work because the mysql_ library doesn't even exist in that version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
     $query_results = mysql_query("SELECT id, fname, lname, email FROM register WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
     $result_set=mysql_query($query_results);
     $fetch=mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
```

Remove a while loop in the code because Query return particular record.